# Installing Mosquitto on Yocto

Tags: ubuntu, cross-compiling, yocto, mosquitto

I am trying to install Mosquitto on an embedded device running a Yocto Pyro distribution. From my research I know I will have to cross-compile the Mosquitto source code in Ubuntu for my target device. My target device is using Linux kernal version 4.1.15 and is using this SOM device https://www.variscite.com/product/system-on-module-som/cortex-a7/dart-6ul-freescale-imx-6ul/#memory.

I have some work to do in figuring out exactly how to complete the cross-compilation as I am a novice in the Linux world, however my question is: what do I do with the compiled code once it has been built in my Ubuntu VM?

Any helpful resources you are aware of for cross-compiling would also be greatly appreciated. Many of the resources I find for installing MQTT on my device require a new build of the OS. Is it possible to install Mosquitto on an existing build?

Comment: You should add the  meta-network layer which hold the bitbake recipe for Mosquitto (https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/85578/).
And adding the mosquito to your image.  Yocto should take care of cross-compiling it.
More info can be found in the Mega Manual of Yocto (https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html), but please select the Pyro version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Pyro really? It's EOL End Of Life! Dead![0]

The mosquitto recipe[2] is part of meta-networking.

[0] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnciwwsvNcc

[1] https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases

[2] https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/85578/